# Is it possible to remove/block a EIGRP neighbors connection via Switch?

Tags: switch, eigrp

I have a 4 routers that connected each other via an multilayer switch. Is it possible to remove/block an EIGRP neighbors via Switch?

For example, I have a topology like this :
[image]

I wanted to remove EIGRP neighbors from RA to RB (10.10.0.2), but PC0 and PC1 still able to ping each other after I removed it via Switch. Is it possible? Thanks.

```
Router0#sh ip eigrp ne
IP-EIGRP neighbors for process 10
H   Address         Interface      Hold Uptime    SRTT   RTO   Q   Seq
                                   (sec)          (ms)        Cnt  Num
0   10.10.3.2       Fa             13   00:14:48  40     1000  0   42
1   10.10.0.2       Fa0/0          11   00:11:53  40     1000  0   42
```

Here's the Core Switch configuration :

```
 hostname Switch
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 10,20
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
 spanning-tree portfast trunk
!
interface FastEthernet0/2
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 10,40
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
 spanning-tree portfast trunk
!
interface FastEthernet0/3
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 30,40
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
 spanning-tree portfast trunk
!
interface FastEthernet0/4
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 20,30
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
 spanning-tree portfast trunk
!

Here's each router configuration:
```

-Router0-

```
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface FastEthernet0/0.10
 encapsulation dot1Q 10
 ip address 10.10.0.1 255.255.255.252
!
interface FastEthernet0/0.20
 encapsulation dot1Q 20
 ip address 10.10.3.1 255.255.255.252
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 ip address 192.168.1.254 255.255.255.0
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
router eigrp 10
 network 10.0.0.0
 network 192.168.0.0
 network 192.168.1.0
 network 192.168.2.0
 network 192.168.3.0
 network 192.168.4.0
 no auto-summary
!
ip classless
ip route 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0 FastEthernet0/1 
!
ip flow-export version 9
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line aux 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
!
end
```

-Router1-

```
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface FastEthernet0/0.10
 encapsulation dot1Q 10
 ip address 10.10.0.2 255.255.255.252
!
interface FastEthernet0/0.20
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface FastEthernet0/0.30
 encapsulation dot1Q 30
 ip address 10.10.1.1 255.255.255.252
 shutdown
!
interface FastEthernet0/0.40
 encapsulation dot1Q 40
 ip address 10.10.1.1 255.255.255.252
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 ip address 192.168.2.254 255.255.255.0
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
router eigrp 10
 network 10.0.0.0
 network 192.168.0.0
 network 192.168.1.0
 network 192.168.2.0
 network 192.168.3.0
 network 192.168.4.0
 no auto-summary
!
ip classless
ip route 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0 FastEthernet0/1 
!
ip flow-export version 9
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line aux 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
!
end
```

-Router2-

```
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface FastEthernet0/0.30
 encapsulation dot1Q 30
 ip address 10.10.2.1 255.255.255.252
!
interface FastEthernet0/0.40
 encapsulation dot1Q 40
 ip address 10.10.1.2 255.255.255.252
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 ip address 192.168.3.254 255.255.255.0
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
router eigrp 1
 auto-summary
!
router eigrp 10
 network 10.0.0.0
 network 192.168.0.0
 network 192.168.1.0
 network 192.168.2.0
 network 192.168.3.0
 network 192.168.4.0
 no auto-summary
!
ip classless
ip route 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0 FastEthernet0/1 
!
ip flow-export version 9
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line aux 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
!
end
```

-Router3-

```
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface FastEthernet0/0.20
 encapsulation dot1Q 20
 ip address 10.10.3.2 255.255.255.252
!
interface FastEthernet0/0.30
 encapsulation dot1Q 30
 ip address 10.10.2.2 255.255.255.252
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 ip address 192.168.4.254 255.255.255.0
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
router eigrp 10
 network 10.0.0.0
 network 192.168.0.0
 network 192.168.1.0
 network 192.168.2.0
 network 192.168.3.0
 network 192.168.4.0
 no auto-summary
!
ip classless
ip route 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0 FastEthernet0/1 
!
ip flow-export version 9
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line aux 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
!
end
```

Comment: You should really use the `no auto-summary` router command, and you should be more specific on your `10.0;0.0` networks since you have those subnetted with a longer mask. Also, remove the static routes you have configured because that defeats the purpose of the routing protocol.

Comment: Roger that, router configuration updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED**

The first thing I want to point out is that when you share only partial information, we have to make assumptions, and they can be wrong.  The more information you give us, the better our answers will be.

Now that you have provided the device configurations, I've taken the liberty of creating a new diagram to show you one way to better represent your network.  This is a logical view that makes the interconnections between the routers much clearer.

[image: Network Diagram]

Now that we can see the true topology, there are a number of ways to accomplish your goal.

**Option 1**. You have to configure static neighbors on all your routers.  The `eigrp neighbor` command uses unicast hellos instead of multicast, so you have to specify who the neighbors are on all routers. For example:

```
router eigrp 1
network 10.0.0.0
network 192.168.0.0
neighbor 10.10.3.2 fa 0/0
```

**Option 2.**  Configure passive interface on the link:

```
router eigrp 1
passive-interface fa0/0.10
```

**Option 3.**  Remove the interface from the routing domain.

```
router eigrp 10
network 10.10.3.0 0.0.0.3
network 192.168.1.0
```

Note that EIGRP does not run on interface fa0/0.10

Comment: Did I need to reconfigure my router from scratch or I just added this static neighbors to my current routers configuration?

Comment: Just and the neighbor commands to your configuration.  As a general rule, you never have to configure your routers from scratch. If something needs to be removed, you can just use the no command.  For example, to remove the eigrp configuration, you just use "no router eigrp".

Comment: So, I just configuring these static neighbors? No need to add any configuration  on switch?

Comment: What is your current switch configuration?  Edit your question to include it.

Comment: Added. I configuring each port that connect to each router with trunk and adding encap dot1q.

Comment: No change to the switch.  But why are your interfaces trunks?  Do you have multiple subinterfaces on your routers?

Comment: Yes, I added 1 sub-interface each routers. So, each routers act like the have two interfaces to the core switch to representate each network on the router as like on the picture on my question. For example I using fa0/0 on RA as 10.10.0.1 and on RB as 10.10.0.2. But also on RA I added a sub-if so, PC3 could ping PC1.

Comment: It's hard to give you advice when we don't have all the information.  Are the interfaces in your diagram all on the same VLAN?  Can you add the router interfaces to your question?

Comment: It's all on the same VLAN.

Comment: Alright, configuration added. I linked a paste o pastebin.

Comment: @Specter, it was not too long. You get 30,000 characters for your question, and the Preformatted-text feature automatically creates scroll boxes for long text. Links can go bad, so please include all the necessary information in the question itself, rather than a link. This site is meant to be an archive for questions and answers, and you cannot guarantee that a link will be active years from now.

Comment: Oh, alright. Note that. Sorry, sir.

Comment: From the excerpt shown from the switch, it seems that the switch has nothing more than VLAN 1 defined. You have to define the VLANs too. This leads me to believe that you didn't understand the part about "_Creating the VLANs_ and setting the port to `mode trunk` would be sufficient" from my previous answer at https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/52639/390191

Comment: @Marc'netztier'Luethi Done adding VLAN on the Core Switch. I updated my Switch configuration. And sorry about that, I'm still learning about VLAN too. Sorry about my incomprehension -/\-

Comment: Also updated the router configuration.